# Why do I get leading zeros when converting from decimal to char in a db2 query?

Tags: db2, datatypes, functions

I have a column named length defined as:

```
TYPE_NAME: DECIMAL 
DATA_TYPE: 3 
COLUMN_SIZE: 9 
BUFFER_LENGTH: 11
DECIMAL_DIGITS: 5 
NUM_PREC_RADIX: 10
```

When I run the following select:

```
select char(length) st_length, length from atable
```

I get leading zeros on the st_length column:

```
st_length   length
0043.00000  43.00000
0043.00000  43.00000
0045.00000  45.00000
0044.00000  44.00000
0044.00000  44.00000
0046.00000  46.00000
```

Why am I getting the leading zeros and how do I get rid of them?

---

**Edit**: I meant to say this earlier but forgot. I'm using db2 v9.5.8 LUW.

---

**Resolution**: My original goal was to get the left most character of the length. I ended up with this:

```
select left(char(cast(length as int)),1) st_length, length from atable
```

which yielded,

```
st_length  length
4          43.00000
4          43.00000
4          45.00000
4          44.00000
4          44.00000
4          46.00000
```

Improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears by design. See [behaviour changes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/i0054264.html) for v9.7 for more.

I suggest you'd need [VARCHAR](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0000869.html) inside [LPAD](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0053529.html) with leading spaces

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  I missed that in the docs.  Also, it didn't help that I was looking at v9.7 docs when referencing the CHAR function and it specifically said leading zeros are omitted. Most db2 instances here are v9.7 but when I double-checked, this one is v9.5.  So, VARCHAR won't work either, according to the v9.5 docs decimal is not an acceptable input to the VARCHAR function, and indeed doesn't work when tried.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use a `CASE` statement to resolve this problem in my situation. `APPLICATION_OID` is a `DECIMAL(17,0)`. You may have to tweek the ranges I the case statements to meet your needs.

```
SELECT LENGTH(CHAR(APPLICATION_OID)), APPLICATION_OID, CHAR(APPLICATION_OID), 
CASE WHEN APPLICATION_OID > 0 AND APPLICATION_OID <= 9 THEN SUBSTR(CHAR(APPLICATION_OID),18,1)
     WHEN APPLICATION_OID > 9 AND APPLICATION_OID <= 99 THEN SUBSTR(CHAR(APPLICATION_OID),17,2)
     WHEN APPLICATION_OID > 99 AND APPLICATION_OID <= 999 THEN SUBSTR(CHAR(APPLICATION_OID),16,3)
END
FROM ABCDEFG.APP_MSTR
WHERE APPLICATION_OID IN (57,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
WITH UR;
```